# Spark + EMRFS/S3 - Is there a way to read client side encrypted data and write it back using server side encryption?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, encryption

I have a use-case in spark where I have to read data from a S3 that uses client-side encryption, process it and write it back using only server-side encryption. I'm wondering if there's a way to do this in spark?

Currently, I have these options set:

```
spark.hadoop.fs.s3.cse.enabled=true
spark.hadoop.fs.s3.enableServerSideEncryption=true
spark.hadoop.fs.s3.serverSideEncryption.kms.keyId=<kms id here>
```

But obviously, it's ending up using both CSE and SSE while writing the data. So, I'm wondering it it's possible to somehow only set spark.hadoop.fs.s3.cse.enabled to true while reading and then set it to false or maybe another alternative.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Using programmatic configuration to define multiple S3 filesystems:

```
spark.hadoop.fs.s3.cse.enabled=true
spark.hadoop.fs.s3sse.impl=foo.bar.S3SseFilesystem
```

and then add a custom implementation for `s3sse`:

```
package foo.bar

import java.net.URI

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem

class S3SseFilesystem extends S3AFileSystem {
  override def initialize(name: URI, originalConf: Configuration): Unit = {
    val conf = new Configuration()
    // NOTE: no prefix spark.hadoop here
    conf.set("fs.s3.enableServerSideEncryption", "true")
    conf.set("fs.s3.serverSideEncryption.kms.keyId", "<kms id here>")
    super.initialize(name, conf)
  }
}
```

After this, the custom file system can be used with Spark `read` method

```
spark.read.json("s3sse://bucket/prefix")
```

Comment: Those aren't the configuration settings which the s3a users (tip: all lower case, all `fs.s3a`. Don't know whose FS you've extended, but it ain't the apache one. Also: s3a doesn't support S3-CSE, because byte-padding meant it was historically unusable