# Read two files with different authentication tokens in PySpark

Tags: pyspark

I am using `PySpark` to read a couple of files into dataframes, and perform their union. Since the two files have different permission grants, I'm using `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider` to read both the files. However, I'm getting an error when I try to read the second file (either of the files I can read separately, but not together).

Code to read a file:

```py
def read_file(file_path, file_id):
    aws_tokens = get_aws_tokens_for_file(file_id)
    spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.access.key', aws_access_key)
    spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.secret.key', aws_secret_key)
    spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.session.token', aws_session_token)
    spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled', 'true')
    spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider")
    df = spark.read.parquet(file_path)
    return df
```

Now, the following works in two different pyspark-session:

```py
df1 = read_file(file_1_path, file_1_id)
```

```py
df2 = read_file(file_2_path, file_2_id)
```

However, when I try the following, it fails with a `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException`:

```py
df1 = read_file(file_1_path, file_1_id)
df2 = read_file(file_2_path, file_2_id)
df3 = df1.union(df2)
print(df3.count())
```

One reason for this might be that files are actually read from `s3` only when an action is performed, and when the action is performed, the aws-credentials required for both files are different.

So I tried to persist the first file and then read the second file, but that fails with the same exception too:

```py
df1 = read_file(file_1_path, file_1_id)
_ = df1.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK).count()

df2 = read_file(file_2_path, file_2_id) #fails here itself
```

So how do I perform union of two such files which require different aws-authentication credentials?

Answer (score 1):

Spark does on-demand computation, which includes reading data. instances of the S3A FileSystem class will be cached by bucket URI too...changing the config is only going to have effect if the buckets are different.

You can use per-bucket settings to change the credentials/credential provider for different s3 buckets. Provided your data is in separate buckets, that should work. Look at the hadoop s3 docs for the specifics.

Comment: How do I reset the instances of the `s3a file system class`? The datasets are in the same bucket, but I do not have the access to the buckets per say. I'm using an API which grants credentials only to a specific dataset.

Comment: if both sources are from the same bucket, then per-bucket settings won't work for you. Instead, you might consider making a custom filesystem as explained by @olik1 in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62870677/19655 - but you need to know java and then add the jar to spark ...